# Apply CSS rules with lower specificity to an HTML element, overriding the most specific ones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a CSS cascade, of course all the components use the last one, but there's a specific component that I don't want it to use the latter CSS rules (business-frontpage.css), instead use the rules from the bootstrap.css stylesheet.

Is this possible? How can I do it?
These are my CSS styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme/business-frontpage.css">
```

I want the following element to use only styles from the bootstrap.css, not the ones from the theme (business-frontpage.css).

```
<datepicker></datepicker>
```

Comment: Can't you just remove whatever styles there are for datepicker from business-frontpage.css?

Comment: @RyanVincent - OP wants `<datepicker></datepicker>` to use the styles from bootstrap.css not business-frontpage.css

Comment: As @BSMP says I want <datepicker></datepicker> to use the styles from bootstrap.css not business-frontpage.css instead of taking the business-frontpage.css which is the last in the css cascade

Comment: Are you using LESS? You can create a specific new LESS Stylesheet for that datepicker element, by just inheriting styles for datepicker from bootstrap.css.
Else, you just need to locate all styles from bootstrap.css for datepicker element, copy them to you new stylesheet and put it after the business-frontpage.css. Quick and dirty

Comment: @RyanVincent I cannot just add a class to datepicker because is a component (is composed by a lot of html), so in order to do not touch and custom a lot of css, that maybe it will just broke everything. If I can do that the element take the bootstrap.css the component will be shown as expected.

Comment: Basically.. **you can't**. You need to reconsider your overriding styles.

Comment: What about inline CSS for datepicker?

Comment: Then just don't use a class for that datetime element. Just go with specificity rules. For example let's say your <datepicker> element is inside other HTML elements, you can be as expressive as you want in your CSS and not touch the component. Though if you want to change something in the future in markup it will be pain.
But there is only one way and that way is to create another file to override the business-frontpage.css

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments, it looks like you have two options. You can take the styles from the bootstrap.css and either:

1. Create a custom style sheet
2. Copy the datepicker CSS
3. Paste it into the new stylesheet
4. Then place the external stylesheet after business-frontpage.css

Or

1. Copy datepicker CSS
2. Paste the CSS into a `<style></style>` in the `<head></head>` of your page